# Entry Count plugin performance / template optimisation

Tags: entry, performance, eager-loading, count

I'm using Ben Croker's Entry Count plugin in my News channel but have noticed a huge performance hit, I know its probably down to how I am loading the entries in to my template so I am looking for some help on that please.

The News Channel where it is being used has tens of thousands of entries.

The server logs highlighted this query https://pastebin.com/02uF0Mat taking up to 3 minutes to complete, therefore maxing the CPU and crashing the site.

My template code:

```
{% cache globally using key "trending-news" %}                                  
    {% set countedEntries = craft.entryCount.entries.section('news').limit(4) %}

    {% for entry in countedEntries %}                       
        <p>{{ entry.postDate.format('jS F Y') }}<br/><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }} </a></p>                       
    {% endfor %}
{% endcache %}
```

So I think this code is loading thousands of news entries and then displaying only 4, is there a way I can just load the top 4 only?

Massive thanks in advance!

Comment: You would have to change the php code in the plugin in order to boost it's performance. Would you do that? This function https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-entry-count/blob/master/entrycount/services/EntryCountService.php#L38 causes a really heavy overload

Comment: Yeah I could do that, which part?

Comment: please see my answer (note if you already saw it, i edited it multiple times should be the final version for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested since I don't have time to load the plugin, so please comment if there is a syntax error but changing [this](https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-entry-count/blob/master/entrycount/services/EntryCountService.php#L38)

```
// get all records from DB ordered by count descending
$entryCountRecords = EntryCountRecord::model()->findAll(array(
    'order'=>'count desc'
));
```

To something like the following should work

```
public function getEntries($limit = null)
{
    $where = [
        'order' => 'count desc' 
    ];
    if($limit !== null){
        $where['limit'] = $limit;
    }
    // get all records from DB ordered by count descending
    $entryCountRecords = EntryCountRecord::model()->findAll($where);
   ....
```

And in your template

```
{% set countedEntries = craft.entryCount.entries(4).section('news').limit(4) %}
```

Explanation: you include a limit to the query that fetches all entries to load the same amount like the `ElementCriteriaModel`

Edit: Maybe you have to change [this](https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-entry-count/blob/master/entrycount/variables/EntryCountVariable.php#L26) to

```
public function getEntries($limit = null)
{
    return craft()->entryCount->getEntries($limit);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this whole answer worked, including the final edit.